# Split word containing unicode character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

I am working on an NLP project involving emojis in tweets.

An example of the tweets is given here: 
`"sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once"`

My problem is that `once` is considered as one word so I would like to split that unique word into two so that my tweet look like this: 
`"sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once "`

Note that I already have the compiled regexp containing each emojis!

I am looking for an efficient way of doing that since I have hundreds of thousands tweets but I can't figure out where to start.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once"
>>> re.findall("(\w+|[^\w ]+)",s)
['sometimes', 'i', 'wish', 'i', 'wa', 'an', 'octopus', 'so', 'i', 'could', 'slap', '8', 'people', 'at', 'once', '']
```

If you need them as a single space-delimited string again, just join them:

```
>>> " ".join(re.findall("(\w+|[^\w ]+)",s))
'sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once '
```

edit: fixed.

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer, can you explain to me how the regexp finds the boundary between the actual word and the unicode character?

Comment: @ThomasReynaud It first tries to match a sequence of word characters (`\w`), no emoji is part of that class. Once it matched `"once"`, the match stops, because it can't match any more word characters. So from that position, it searches for the next match, just trying to find *anything* that isn't a space character. Actually, this method is flawed if the emoji isn't at the end, I think, let me test some more.

Comment: @ThomasReynaud I changed the regex slightly. It will now either match word character sequences, or sequences of anything that is neither a space nor a word character.

Comment: Thanks! Was too much focused on using my emojis regexp, I missed the easy solution. Just a note (it doesn't matter at all in my case) for future readers, this doesn't parse `""` into `"  "`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` to introduce a space:

```
re.sub(r'(\W+)(?= |$)', r' \1', string)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> string
'sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once\xf0\x9f\x90\x99'
>>> re.sub(r'(\W+)(?= |$)', r' \1', string)
'sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once \xf0\x9f\x90\x99'

>>> string = 'sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once" foobar'
>>> re.sub(r'(\W+)(?= |$)', r' \1', string)
'sometimes i wish i wa an octopus so i could slap 8 people at once \xf0\x9f\x90\x99 foobar'
```